# Milancovich analysis

Tags: climate-change, models

I would like to show the change in temperatures since 1960 until today. I have thought about creating two time blocks, e.g. from 1960-1970 and from 2010-2020! Then I want to average the data of these two time blocks (i.e. the data from 1960-1970 and from 2010-2020) and then calculate the difference between the two time blocks. Now I wonder if there are rules in the geosciences about how large the time periods should be, because I simply assumed the 10 years. The question for me is what period can be assumed as the minimum to prevent extreme years (either extremely hot or extremely cold) from having a major influence?

Comment: Generally climate sets use 30 year averages in atmospheric sciences to reduce the impact of extreme years/shortterm fluctuations.  That's the standard the NWS uses to calculate longterm means, updating each 10 years.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest thank you very much!

Comment: Does your title refer to Milankovich cycles? If that is the case I'd like to give a warning. Whatever you will find it won't  show any trend induced by the periodic changes of earth relative to the sun.

Comment: Oh I think it is called this way! Is there a nouther way to call this type of time seperated analysis!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common period to use is 30-years, which comes from the idea of [climate normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climatological_normal) used in NWP.  Using only 10 years even global mean temperature will see the influence of a single large El Nino or prolonged La Nina events, which probably isn't what you're after.  If you were writing a paper that used 30-years means, the reviewer probably wouldn't question it; if you used 20-year means they might ask you to justify it; if you used 10-year means you'd probably be criticized for it.

Regardless of what period you pick, it's always a good idea to also calculate confidence intervals for your means, which can give you a sanity check on whether differences between periods are really notable.  That's sort of one step short of doing formal statistical hypothesis testing.

From the IPCC AR6 glossary, for reference:

> *Climate*: Climate in a narrow sense is usually defined as the average weather, or more rigorously, as the statistical description in terms of the mean and variability of relevant quantities over a period of time ranging from months to thousands or millions of years. The classical period for averaging these variables is **30 years**, as defined by the World Meteorological Organization (WMO). The relevant quantities are most often surface variables such as temperature, precipitation and wind. Climate in a wider sense is the state, including a statistical description, of the climate system.

and,

> *Global warming*: Global warming refers to the increase in global surface temperature relative to a baseline reference period, averaging over a period sufficient to remove interannual variations (e.g., **20 or 30 years**). A common choice for the baseline is 1850-1900 (the earliest period of reliable observations with sufficient geographic coverage), with more modern baselines used depending upon the application.